# jQuery doesn't return the correct ID when I click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use PHP to display some results from the DB.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
print "
   <tr id = '".$row[0]."' class = 'fila'>
         <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxx[]' value = '".$row[0]."'</td>
         <td>".$row[1]."</td>   
         <td>".$row[3]."</td>
         <td>".$row[4]."</td>
    </tr>
";
}
```

With jQuery, I want to display the ID of each row (TR) if it's clicked.

I have this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fila").click(function(){
       var id = $('.fila').attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

**Problem**: It always displays the same ID when I click in different rows, when in fact, I look at source code, and each TR has its ID, which are different because they are selected from DB.

Comment: Try just placing `alert(this.id)` inside the click function, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var id = $('.fila').attr('id');
```

Should be

```
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Otherwise you aren't operating on the right row. `$('.fila')` selects **all** of the rows, not the one that you're attaching the `click` to.

If you use `$(this)`, it will alert the id of itself, and in this case itself is the correct row you just clicked on.

Comment: Every time someone uses `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id`, God kills a lolcat.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fila").click(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       alert(id);
    });
});
```

`$(this)` is the element that was clicked, within the click event handler.

You could alternatively use this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fila").click(function(){
       var id = this.id;
       alert(id);
    });
});
```

It doesn't rely on jQuery to get the id of the clicked element.  They both achieve the same result, but the 2nd is "slightly" more efficient.

Comment: Relative to each other, directly accessing the property is vastly more efficient.  Relative to how people perceive time, they're essentially identical.

Comment: No worries mate - whichever way suits, you've got both options :)